# material-ui not working on safari

Tags: safari, material-ui

I am using Material UI in my project.I have built the project using browserify. The.The project works fine on Chrome, Firefox and IE also,but not on Safari.

Its a simple selectable list,On the Click of each item I am trying to open a dialogue box. But each of these list items are not working correctly.

```
<SelectableList value={2} subheader="SelectableContacts"> 
<ListItem value={2} primaryText="Raquel Parrado" /> 
<ListItem value={2} primaryText="Raquel Parrado" /> 
</SelectableList>
```

I am not able to select a particular option. On select the complete component gets selected and not the clicked item.

[What am I missing here?](https://github.com/dhruvdatt/MaterialUi-Safari)

Comment: Your codes will help to understand the issue..
please consider posting the relevant codes and exact issue example...
See how can you create a [minimum complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  as well...

Comment: I have a simple selectable list,On the Click of each item I am trying to       open a dialog.But each of these list items are not working correctly.   `<SelectableList value={2} subheader="SelectableContacts">`  `<ListItem value={2}  primaryText="Raquel Parrado" />`            `<ListItem value={2}  primaryText="Raquel Parrado" />` `</SelectableList>`                                                                                  So what is happening here is I am not able to select a perticular option.  If a select it the complete Component is selected and does not select the clicked item.

Comment: this is a sample of what I am trying out. [Trying to get maerial ui work on Safari](https://github.com/dhruvdatt/MaterialUi-Safari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some issue in the safari for windows.I have tried it on mac version of safari and it turns out all good.
Is there any specific reason behind this..?